# Does reddit use Amazon Cloud Search?

Tags: amazon-web-services, reddit, amazon-cloudsearch

I read in reddit wiki that reddit moved to indextrunk but when I reviewed run.py file I found that there is keys like Cloud_Search_Api_key ... So I guessed it is using Amazon cloud search . If this true what are the values that should be changed in run.py to make cloudsearch works? and what is subreddit_cloud_api_key?

Thanks

Comment: Couldn't you ask reddit?

Comment: I really wonder why there is a reddit tag here!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure Reddit uses Cloudsearch. <s>Their [Github FAQ](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/FAQ) claims they use Indextank, but</s> IndexTank has been [shut down since April 2012](https://twitter.com/indextank/status/188396462529454081). If you search on Reddit and highlight the "δ" symbol, it will show text like "δ converted query to cloudsearch syntax: (and (field text 'search') (field text 'terms'))".

I'm not too familiar with Python or AWS, but it looks like CLOUDSEARCH_SEARCH_API and the other similar variables are URLs that Amazon calls [Endpoints](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/endpoints.html).

The variable names in reddit/r2/run.ini contain SEARCH and DOC, mirroring Amazon's documentation. Also, [cloudsearch.py](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/blob/master/r2/r2/lib/cloudsearch.py#L519) makes an HTTP connection to that variable:

```
search_api = g.CLOUDSEARCH_SEARCH_API
//...
connection = httplib.HTTPConnection(search_api, 80)
```

So you would probably set CLOUDSEARCH_SEARCH_API with the URL to your Cloudsearch endpoint.

**EDIT**: [Kemitche has answered this on Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/redditdev/comments/wqx7o/does_reddit_using_amazon_cloud_search/c5fut4i). Unlike me, he knows what he's talking about, so take a look.